# How to set a Template to a ListViewItem in C#

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app

What steps do I need to follow to create on the XAML a ItemTemplate and set this template to a ListViewItem from the C# code. 
I know that ListViewItem has the property Template that I can assign one to it, but I did not succeed.

Comment: Show us what you tried

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal I could not find a way to try anything. I tried to set the ListView.ItemTemplate insider the XAML, but this didn't work at all.

Comment: Why would you ever need to do this??

Comment: @Jessica I'm building a Tab management for one of my apps, and each tab is a ListViewItem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `ItemTemplate` before loading the items in the `ListView`.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="listViewItemTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <ListView x:Name="listview"/>
</Grid>
```

And in the code-behind:

```
public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        listview.ItemTemplate = listViewItemTemplate;
        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
        {
            listview.Items.Add("Item " + x);
        }
    }
```

I hope this helps.

But in the case of the `Template` for a single `ListViewItem` you should be looking for a `Style` in the `generic.xaml` file in the SDK folder. It is provided by Microsoft as a default resource file.

You can either copy the default template from the above file or create a new `Style` property in your page resources and assign this style to your `ListViewItem`. Have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299136.aspx).

Comment: This definitely was helpful, but I needed to change a few things to work out. As I was trying to set a ListViewItem.Template (not ItemTemplate) I needed to use ControlTemplate instead of DataTemplate.
The code could not find listViewItemTemplate so I wrote this instead: `(ControlTemplate)this.Resources["listViewItemTemplate"]`

After that it worked pretty great! Thank you!

Comment: Yes, that's right. To access the page resources, you need to get them through the resources property.